# Error after trimming illumina adapters

Tags: ngs, cutadapt, loop

I am removing illumina adapters of the NGS data with a loop. My NGS data is storage in /data/HTS_seq/.
I used this function:

```
 for infile in /data/HTS_seq/*_read1.fastq; do outfile=$infile\_trim.fastq cutadapt -a AGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCAC -e 0.1 -O 3 -m 30 --max-n 2 -o $outfile $infile; done

 for infile in /data/HTS_seq/*_read2.fastq; do outfile=$infile\_trim.fastq cutadapt -a AGATCGGAAGAGCGTCGTGTAGGGAAAGAGTGTA -e 0.1 -O 3 -m 30 --max-n 2 -o $outfile $infile; done
```

and It gives to me this error:

```
  IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/data/HTS_seq/PV589_03664AAB_AGGACT_read1.fastq/_trim.fastq'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/cutadapt", line 10, in <module>
cutadapt.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cutadapt/scripts/cutadapt.py", line 652, in main
options.discard_untrimmed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cutadapt/scripts/cutadapt.py", line 327, in trimmed_and_untrimmed_files
trimmed = untrimmed = xopen(output_path, 'w')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cutadapt/xopen.py", line 178, in xopen
return open(filename, mode)
      IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/data/HTS_seq/PV589_03664AAB_AGGACT_read1.fastq/_trim.fastq'
```

Which is my error?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you aren't actually setting the `$outfile` variable. Your loop has this basic format:

```
for var in *; do newVar="something" command $newVar; done
```

For example:

```
$ for var in 1 2 3 4; do newVar="new:$var" echo "$var: $newVar"; done
1: 
2: 
3: 
4:
```

As you can see, `newVar` is never actually being set. That's because setting a variable is its own operation. So you need to do that, end it with a control character like `;`, or `&`, or a newline, and *then* run your `cutadapt`:

```
$ for var in 1 2 3 4; do newVar="new:$var"; echo "$var: $newVar"; done
1: new:1
2: new:2
3: new:3
4: new:4
```

Or, with your data:

```
for infile in /data/HTS_seq/*_read1.fastq; do 
    outfile="$infile"_trim.fastq 
    cutadapt -a AGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCAC \ 
      -e 0.1 -O 3 -m 30 --max-n 2 -o "$outfile" "$infile"
done


for infile in /data/HTS_seq/*_read2.fastq; do 
    outfile="$infile"_trim.fastq
    cutadapt -a AGATCGGAAGAGCGTCGTGTAGGGAAAGAGTGTA \ 
      -e 0.1 -O 3 -m 30 --max-n 2 -o $outfile $infile
done
```

But that would give a weird file name, like `foo_S1_L001_read1.fastq_trim.fastq`. You probably want names like `foo_S1_L001_read1_trim.fastq` instead, so you would want:

```
for infile in /data/HTS_seq/*_read1.fastq; do 
    outfile="${infile%.fastq}"_trim.fastq
    cutadapt -a AGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCAC \ 
      -e 0.1 -O 3 -m 30 --max-n 2 -o "$outfile" "$infile"
done


for infile in /data/HTS_seq/*_read2.fastq; do 
    outfile="${infile%.fastq}"_trim.fastq
    cutadapt -a AGATCGGAAGAGCGTCGTGTAGGGAAAGAGTGTA \ 
      -e 0.1 -O 3 -m 30 --max-n 2 -o $outfile $infile
done
```

---

Now, the specific error you show makes me think that isn't the command you ran. Could you perhaps have run this one instead by mistake (note the `/` instead of `\` before the `_trim.fastq`)?

```
for infile in /data/HTS_seq/*_read1.fastq; do
 outfile=$infile/_trim.fastq cutadapt -a AGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCAC \ 
-e 0.1 -O 3 -m 30 --max-n 2 -o $outfile $infile
done
```

Your error message is:

```
  IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/data/HTS_seq/PV589_03664AAB_AGGACT_read1.fastq/_trim.fastq'
```

Which means that `cutadapt` tried to open `/data/HTS_seq/PV589_03664AAB_AGGACT_read1.fastq/` as a directory and then look for a file named `_trim.fastq` inside it. The only way I can think that this would happen is if you ran the command I gave above and not the one you show in your question.

Comment: It works! Thank you Terdon

Answer (score -1):

There is a bug here

```
/data/HTS_seq/*_read1.fastq
```

This will go to your root directory `/` and there is definiately no folder called `data` in the root. To prove it type `ls /` and that is where the command is pointing, then compare this to `ls ./`.

To solve it go to the directory `HTS_seq` and type `pwd` then copy and paste the directory structure. I suspect `./data/HTS_seq` will solve it

```
 for infile in ./data/HTS_seq; ...
```

This will look for the folder `data` in your current working directory rather than the root directory.

---

Okay you've been assigned /data as root ... no biggie.

```
PV589_03664AAB_AGGACT_read1.fastq/_trim.fastq
```

Why is `/` in the file name? What happens if you `ls /data/HTS_seq/PV589_03664AAB_AGGACT_read1.fastq/_trim.fastq`?
and `ls /data/HTS_seq/` Finally could you please `ls /data/HTS_seq/PV589_03664AAB_AGGACT_read1.fastq\/_trim.fastq`?

The `\/` is important. What I think has happened is a `/` is in the file name and that will cause problems because it will think that `_trim.fastq` is a directory when its part of a file name, and would explain the error.

Then do the same thing using `head` instead of `ls` see what happens.

If the last `ls` and `head` works then rename the files by typing `rename` in the command line. If `rename` works it will be easy to remove `/` from all your files using the power of the `rename` function (its a Perl function BTW).

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks you for your answer. I typed pwd in HTS_seq folder and I got this direction: /data/HTS_seq                                                                                                 Anyways I typed the code with the . :                                                                                                              for infile in ./data/HTS_seq/*_read1.fastq; do outfile=$infile\_trim.fastq cutadapt -a AGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCAC -e 0.1 -O 3 -m 30 --max-n 2 -o $outfile $infile; done and I got the same error. Which is my mistake? Thanks you

Comment: Hi @AdriánP.L. please try the above, I should have read the error more carefully first time around

Comment: You can never have a `/` in a file name. The `/` alone with `\0` are the _only_ two characters that can never be in file names.